# Correct phrase to use about feeling before actually happen

Tags: word-usage, usage, phrase-usage

I want to say someone about miss him already before he actually leaving.

Can i say

> I already miss you from now on

Comment: Your question is good but it will be best answered on the English Language Learners site.

Answer (score 1):

The "from now on" is redundant and not idiomatic, but "I already miss you" is acceptable and will be understood.

"I miss you already" is more common, in my experience.